# Python Script to Fetch Queries from Splunk

Tags: python, splunk

How can I use the urllib module in Python to get the HTML content from Splunk after logging in and running a query?

I understand we can do it by `curl` if we have CLI access. What about GUI?

Suppose I have my credentials and in one script it should return query after getting my credentials validated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Splunk SDK for Python, as doing all the parsing yourself will be a significant amount of work. There is some great documentation on the Python SDK [here](http://dev.splunk.com/python)